# Null Pointer Exception on child in onMeasure() : futuresimple/floating-action-button

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, floating-action-button

[Android Floating Action Button Lib Used](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/)

I created Floating Action Menu in `xml` file and creating dynamic Floating Action button under this Floating Action Menu. I am setting image bitmap on each FAB. At some particular condition, I have to remove all buttons under Floating Action Menu. But on `removeView()` method, I am getting `Null Pointer Exception` on child object, when it is trying to get visibility of child in `onMeasure()` method. Below is stack trace and my code.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
        at com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu.onMeasure(FloatingActionsMenu.java:224)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1263)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:337)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1196)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1409)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Z
```

Code for adding an removing Floating action button dynamically:

```
       @Override
       public void onTap() {

                if (menuMultipleActions != null) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= mSelectedImages.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("i value ==> " + i);
                menuMultipleActions.removeView(menuMultipleActions.getChildAt(i));
          }
         }
         mSelectedImages.clear();
      }


   @Override
     public void onPictureTaken(String filePath) {
          mSelectedImages.add(filePath);
          menuMultipleActions = (FloatingActionsMenu) findViewById(R.id.multiple_action);
          Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "size = " + mSelectedImages.size(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      if (mSelectedImages.size() > 0) {
             for (int num = 0; num < mSelectedImages.size(); num++) {
                 floatingActionButton = new        com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton(getBaseContext());
                   floatingActionButton.setSize(com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.SIZE_MINI);
                    floatingActionButton.setImageBitmap(getImageFromPath(mSelectedImages.get(num)));
                 floatingActionButton.setId(num);
                 menuMultipleActions.addButton(floatingActionButton);
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the method onMeasure(). insluding line FloatingActionsMenu.java:224 ?

Comment: https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/getbase/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionsMenu.java

Comment: Could you try using menuMultipleActions.removeButton() instead of removeView ? Beacuse it internally manipulates some flags in the method for its child .

Comment: I hope your issue is solved ?

Comment: Not yet, this didn't work, getting same error again and again.

Comment: Could you update the latest code.

Comment: Is it possible that you need to remove the children in descending order?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `menuMultipleActions.removeButton()` instead of `removeView()` method.  Internally the `removeButton` manipulates some flags.

[FloatingActionButton.java](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/getbase/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionsMenu.java)

Comment: `if (menuMultipleActions != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= mSelectedImages.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("i value ==> " + i);
                menuMultipleActions.removeButton((FloatingActionButton)menuMultipleActions.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }`

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with the code given. Firstly, as Viswanath points out above using removeView() as below always crashes (regardless of the loop)

```
menuMultipleActions.removeView(menuMultipleActions.getChildAt(0));
```

The second issue is that the loop will always crash part way through because as you delete each button the number of views in menuMultipleActions decreases by one. The solution to this would either be to loop backwards, or to always delete the zeroth child eg

```
if (menuMultipleActions != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelectedImages.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("i value ==> " + i);
        menuMultipleActions.removeButton((FloatingActionButton) menuMultipleActions.getChildAt(0));
    }
}
```

Although I might be more inclined to use menuMultipleActions.getChildCount() as a safer way of finding the number of buttons.

The more general solution, which will work in a loop or to remove any single button by id would be to to use findViewById to find the button prior to deleting it. eg

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) menuMultipleActions.findViewById(ButtonId);
if (fab != null) menuMultipleActions.removeButton(fab);
```

If a label is set for the FloatingActionButton you can also use findViewByTag because the implementation uses the label as the tag.